# Google VR View wrapping issue at the top and bottom, any suggestions or replacement?

Tags: google-vr, 360-panorama

I was trying to implement a 360 image viewer on my website and came across Google VR-View, it works but has a terrible issue with image wrapping at the top and bottom, it's even in their example:

https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview-web

I've noticed that when I switch to full screen and zoom out it works fine but obviously it's not a solution.

Anyone knows how to get around this? or maybe have a replacement for google vr view (which supports gyro on mobile)?

Thank You,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this working pretty well
https://pannellum.org/